# Como puedo sumar valores de dos columnas calculadas en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hola chicos quisiera ver si me pueden orientar, tengo un problema con una consulta, la cual es esta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT proceso2 AS 'Proceso', 
SUM(proceso_op) AS 'Programado',
SUM(CASE WHEN cr = 1 THEN proceso_op ELSE 0 END) AS 'ATN', 
SUM(CASE WHEN cr = 7 THEN proceso_op ELSE 0 END) AS 'Cod_no_localizado' FROM tbuniverso GROUP BY proceso2
```

Lo que quiero es calcular una nueva columna llamada "Atendidos_totales" la cual sera la sumatoria de las columnas que calcule anteriormente con alias "ATN" y "Cod_no_localizado", pero como estas son alias no puedo hacer calculos con ellas, ya he probado varias cosas pero no lo resulevo. Ejemplo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT proceso2 AS 'Proceso', 
SUM(proceso_op) AS 'Programado',
SUM(CASE WHEN cr = 1 THEN proceso_op ELSE 0 END) AS 'ATN', 
SUM(CASE WHEN cr = 7 THEN proceso_op ELSE 0 END) AS 'Cod_no_localizado', 
SUM((SUM(CASE WHEN cr = 1 THEN proceso_op ELSE 0 END))-(SUM(CASE WHEN cr = 7 THEN proceso_op ELSE 0 END))) AS 'Atendido_Total'  FROM tbuniverso GROUP BY proceso2
```

Aqui lo que intente fue hacer de nuevo las dos sumatorias que hice primero para volver a generar los valores e intentar sumarlos pero me marca error: *#1111 - Invalido uso de función en grupo* Esto solo fue una prueba y mas o menos para que entiendan lo que quiero lograr. Espero me puedan ayudar :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear una tabla derivada y referenciar las columnas en una consulta externa asi:

```
SELECT Proceso, Programado, ATN, Cod_no_localizado, ATN+Cod_no_localizado AS 'Atendidos_totales'
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT proceso2 AS 'Proceso', 
    SUM(proceso_op) AS 'Programado',
    SUM(CASE WHEN cr = 1 THEN proceso_op ELSE 0 END) AS 'ATN', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN cr = 7 THEN proceso_op ELSE 0 END) AS 'Cod_no_localizado' FROM 
    tbuniverso GROUP BY proceso2
) AS t;
```

Comment: WoW funciono a la perfección GRACIAS.

Comment: Y si necesitara hacer otra suma pero con Atendidos_totales para sacar una columna "Pendientes"?

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolví, gracias por tu respuesta me abriste la mente a las subconsultas jaja, aqui la solucion a mi segundo problema, no es lo mas eficiente pero me da el resultado esperado:

```
SELECT Proceso, Programado, ATN, Cod_no_localizado, Atendidos_totales, Programado-Atendidos_totales AS 'Pendientes' FROM (SELECT Proceso, Programado, ATN, Cod_no_localizado, ATN+Cod_no_localizado AS 'Atendidos_totales'
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT proceso2 AS 'Proceso', 
    SUM(proceso_op) AS 'Programado',
    SUM(CASE WHEN cr = 1 THEN proceso_op ELSE 0 END) AS 'ATN', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN cr = 7 THEN proceso_op ELSE 0 END) AS 'Cod_no_localizado' FROM 
    tbuniverso GROUP BY proceso2
) AS t) AS e
```